# Haxe can implement multi interfaces?

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop, openfl

I have the haxe code from AS3HX that converts actionscript3 to haxe. Please see the below:

```
class Container extends UIComponent implements IContainer implements IDataRenderer implements IFocusManagerContainer implements IListItemRenderer implements IRawChildrenContainer 
{
    public var verticalScrollPolicy(get, set) : String;
    public var creatingContentPane(get, set) : Bool;
    public var clipContent(get, set) : Bool;
    ...
    ...
}
```

But FlashDevelop always say "You can only implement an interface". I want to know if Haxe can implement multi interfaces?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see https://haxe.org/manual/types-interfaces.html

> While a class may only have one parent class, it may implement multiple interfaces through multiple implements keywords

Comment: I see this, but FlashDevelop always say : src/mx/core/Container.hx:42: lines 42-2540 : You can only implement an interface. Why and how to avoid this error?

Comment: Check all interfaces above, don't they have errors?

Comment: Do you have the same error when trying to compile directly from the commandline ?

Comment: I check each interface, and fix some bugs. It seems to solve this issue. Thank you!!!